# What top-level domains does youtube have?

Tags: youtube, dns, domain-name

I am trying to identify youtube link (generally), and I wonder what top-level domains is youtube using?

So far I know about:

- .com (youtube.com)
- .be (youtu.be)

Are there any others?

PS: for those looking for checking youtube/vimeo video particulary I would recommend to check [how to check the valid Youtube url using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256930/how-to-check-the-valid-youtube-url-using-jquery) ...

Comment: ...oh this question is very much about programming and software development... is it service specific? yes. But otherwise it's the same thing as when someone would ask about proper constants. One of the answers even provides regex code how to match them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51848061/1835470

Answer (score 22, accepted):

At the moment, YouTube videos can be accessed by two kinds of link, either the usual URL generated by the UI itself, as you click from one video to the next:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRgl-78sDX2
```

Or through a sharing URL, created within the UI by clicking the "share" button:

```
https://youtu.be/6DzSAaNQHR8
```

Regarding the second part of your question, what domains are required for access to YouTube?  Unfortunately this is a moving target, as the YouTube changes.  At the time of writing (Mar 2015), that list is as follows:

```
*.youtube.com
*.googlevideo.com
*.ytimg.com
```

In addition to the core domains above, some ancillary domains are also needed to display the ads, etc on most YouTube pages:

```
apis.google.com
*.googleusercontent.com
*.gstatic.com
```

The bulk of the traffic itself comes from *.googlevideo.com.  Beginning in late 2014, YouTube started progressively enabling SSL on the youtube.com and googlevideo.com domains.  You'll need to be aware of this if you're using this information on a filtering or caching device.

Also note this was tested through a browser; native clients (iOS, Android, etc) may operate differently.

Answer (score 9):

I have discovered these **Youtube domains** so far:

```
youtube.com // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfGZ8NyGFS8
youtu.be // https://youtu.be/dfGZ8NyGFS8
youtube-nocookie.com // https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/dfGZ8NyGFS8
```

also `youtube.com` has a mobile version on subdomain:

```
m.youtube.com // https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=dfGZ8NyGFS8
```

I use this list for PHP function [`parse_url`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id) question usefull too.

Comment: As you've showed examples of video urls - here's another embed under `youtube.com` : `https://www.youtube.com/embed/s8XIgR5OGJc`

Comment: Yes @jave.web, but it's on same domain as first example. In my answer is link to plenty others Youtube URL examples.

Comment: yes I've noticed, I just though this was important as sidenote, but in the end this answer is really just about youtube domains, not IDs :-) (the real guess-dark-magic issue)

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to catch youtube video links I am using this regexp part I don't know they use national domains for example if you go to youtube.mx they redirect you back to .com with Mexico localizations... I guess they figured out that they cannot host content on some national domains for example if you use domain of Saudi Arabia you have to accept all local laws of Saudi Arabia and if somebody put content that is in violation of their laws owner of website might be in serious legal trouble... so they are using .com for everything and keep content under jurisdiction and laws of US

```
            https?:\/\/                 # Either http or https
            (?:[\w]+\.)*                # Optional subdomains
            (?:                         # Group host alternatives.
            youtu\.be/                  # Either youtu.be,
            | youtube\.com              # or youtube.com
            | youtube-nocookie\.com     # or youtube-nocookie.com
            )                           # End Host Group
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are all (**147**) top-level URLs which redirected to `youtube.com` that I could find (see below for how I got these URLs):

```
www.youtube.ae  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=AE
www.youtube.at  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=AT
www.youtube.az  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=AZ
www.youtube.ba  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=BA
www.youtube.be  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=BE
www.youtube.bg  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=BG
www.youtube.bh  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=BH
www.youtube.bo  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=BO
www.youtube.by  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=BY
www.youtube.ca  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=CA
www.youtube.cat https://www.youtube.com/?gl=ES
www.youtube.ch  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=CH
www.youtube.cl  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=CL
www.youtube.co  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=CO
www.youtube.co.ae   https://www.youtube.com/?gl=AE
www.youtube.co.at   https://www.youtube.com/?gl=AT
www.youtube.co.cr   https://www.youtube.com/?gl=CR
www.youtube.co.hu   https://www.youtube.com/?gl=HU
www.youtube.co.id   https://www.youtube.com/?gl=ID
www.youtube.co.il   https://www.youtube.com/?gl=IL
www.youtube.co.in   https://www.youtube.com/?gl=IN
www.youtube.co.jp   https://www.youtube.com/?gl=JP
www.youtube.co.ke   https://www.youtube.com/?gl=KE
www.youtube.co.kr   https://www.youtube.com/?gl=KR
www.youtube.co.ma   https://www.youtube.com/?gl=MA
www.youtube.co.nz   https://www.youtube.com/?gl=NZ
www.youtube.co.th   https://www.youtube.com/?gl=TH
www.youtube.co.tz   https://www.youtube.com/?gl=TZ
www.youtube.co.ug   https://www.youtube.com/?gl=UG
www.youtube.co.uk   https://www.youtube.com/?gl=GB
www.youtube.co.ve   https://www.youtube.com/?gl=VE
www.youtube.co.za   https://www.youtube.com/?gl=ZA
www.youtube.co.zw   https://www.youtube.com/?gl=ZW
www.youtube.com https://www.youtube.com/
www.youtube.com.ar  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=AR
www.youtube.com.au  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=AU
www.youtube.com.az  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=AZ
www.youtube.com.bd  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=BD
www.youtube.com.bh  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=BH
www.youtube.com.bo  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=BO
www.youtube.com.br  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=BR
www.youtube.com.by  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=BY
www.youtube.com.co  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=CO
www.youtube.com.do  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=DO
www.youtube.com.ec  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=EC
www.youtube.com.ee  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=EE
www.youtube.com.eg  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=EG
www.youtube.com.es  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=ES
www.youtube.com.gh  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=GH
www.youtube.com.gr  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=GR
www.youtube.com.gt  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=GT
www.youtube.com.hk  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=HK
www.youtube.com.hn  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=HN
www.youtube.com.hr  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=HR
www.youtube.com.jm  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=JM
www.youtube.com.jo  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=JO
www.youtube.com.kw  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=KW
www.youtube.com.lb  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=LB
www.youtube.com.lv  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=LV
www.youtube.com.ly  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=LY
www.youtube.com.mk  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=MK
www.youtube.com.mt  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=MT
www.youtube.com.mx  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=MX
www.youtube.com.my  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=MY
www.youtube.com.ng  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=NG
www.youtube.com.ni  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=NI
www.youtube.com.om  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=OM
www.youtube.com.pa  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=PA
www.youtube.com.pe  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=PE
www.youtube.com.ph  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=PH
www.youtube.com.pk  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=PK
www.youtube.com.pt  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=PT
www.youtube.com.py  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=PY
www.youtube.com.qa  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=QA
www.youtube.com.ro  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=RO
www.youtube.com.sa  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=SA
www.youtube.com.sg  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=SG
www.youtube.com.sv  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=SV
www.youtube.com.tn  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=TN
www.youtube.com.tr  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=TR
www.youtube.com.tw  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=TW
www.youtube.com.ua  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=UA
www.youtube.com.uy  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=UY
www.youtube.com.ve  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=VE
www.youtube.cr  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=CR
www.youtube.cz  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=CZ
www.youtube.de  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=DE
www.youtube.dk  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=DK
www.youtube.ee  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=EE
www.youtube.es  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=ES
www.youtube.fi  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=FI
www.youtube.fr  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=FR
www.youtube.ge  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=GE
www.youtube.gr  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=GR
www.youtube.gt  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=GT
www.youtube.hk  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=HK
www.youtube.hr  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=HR
www.youtube.hu  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=HU
www.youtube.ie  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=IE
www.youtube.in  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=IN
www.youtube.iq  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=IQ
www.youtube.is  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=IS
www.youtube.it  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=IT
www.youtube.jo  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=JO
www.youtube.jp  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=JP
www.youtube.kr  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=KR
www.youtube.kz  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=KZ
www.youtube.lk  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=LK
www.youtube.lt  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=LT
www.youtube.lu  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=LU
www.youtube.lv  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=LV
www.youtube.ly  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=LY
www.youtube.ma  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=MA
www.youtube.me  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=ME
www.youtube.mk  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=MK
www.youtube.mx  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=MX
www.youtube.my  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=MY
www.youtube.net.in  https://www.youtube.com/
www.youtube.ng  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=NG
www.youtube.ni  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=NI
www.youtube.nl  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=NL
www.youtube.no  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=NO
www.youtube.pa  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=PA
www.youtube.pe  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=PE
www.youtube.ph  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=PH
www.youtube.pk  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=PK
www.youtube.pl  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=PL
www.youtube.pr  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=PR
www.youtube.pt  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=PT
www.youtube.qa  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=QA
www.youtube.ro  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=RO
www.youtube.rs  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=RS
www.youtube.ru  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=RU
www.youtube.sa  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=SA
www.youtube.se  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=SE
www.youtube.sg  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=SG
www.youtube.si  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=SI
www.youtube.sk  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=SK
www.youtube.sn  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=SN
www.youtube.sv  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=SV
www.youtube.tn  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=TN
www.youtube.tv  https://tv.youtube.com/welcome/
www.youtube.ua  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=UA
www.youtube.ug  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=UG
www.youtube.uy  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=UY
www.youtube.vn  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=VN
www.youtube.voto    https://www.youtube.com/
```

Here is the first column of the above table (suitable for copying and pasting):

```
www.youtube.ae
www.youtube.at
www.youtube.az
www.youtube.ba
www.youtube.be
www.youtube.bg
www.youtube.bh
www.youtube.bo
www.youtube.by
www.youtube.ca
www.youtube.cat
www.youtube.ch
www.youtube.cl
www.youtube.co
www.youtube.co.ae
www.youtube.co.at
www.youtube.co.cr
www.youtube.co.hu
www.youtube.co.id
www.youtube.co.il
www.youtube.co.in
www.youtube.co.jp
www.youtube.co.ke
www.youtube.co.kr
www.youtube.co.ma
www.youtube.co.nz
www.youtube.co.th
www.youtube.co.tz
www.youtube.co.ug
www.youtube.co.uk
www.youtube.co.ve
www.youtube.co.za
www.youtube.co.zw
www.youtube.com
www.youtube.com.ar
www.youtube.com.au
www.youtube.com.az
www.youtube.com.bd
www.youtube.com.bh
www.youtube.com.bo
www.youtube.com.br
www.youtube.com.by
www.youtube.com.co
www.youtube.com.do
www.youtube.com.ec
www.youtube.com.ee
www.youtube.com.eg
www.youtube.com.es
www.youtube.com.gh
www.youtube.com.gr
www.youtube.com.gt
www.youtube.com.hk
www.youtube.com.hn
www.youtube.com.hr
www.youtube.com.jm
www.youtube.com.jo
www.youtube.com.kw
www.youtube.com.lb
www.youtube.com.lv
www.youtube.com.ly
www.youtube.com.mk
www.youtube.com.mt
www.youtube.com.mx
www.youtube.com.my
www.youtube.com.ng
www.youtube.com.ni
www.youtube.com.om
www.youtube.com.pa
www.youtube.com.pe
www.youtube.com.ph
www.youtube.com.pk
www.youtube.com.pt
www.youtube.com.py
www.youtube.com.qa
www.youtube.com.ro
www.youtube.com.sa
www.youtube.com.sg
www.youtube.com.sv
www.youtube.com.tn
www.youtube.com.tr
www.youtube.com.tw
www.youtube.com.ua
www.youtube.com.uy
www.youtube.com.ve
www.youtube.cr
www.youtube.cz
www.youtube.de
www.youtube.dk
www.youtube.ee
www.youtube.es
www.youtube.fi
www.youtube.fr
www.youtube.ge
www.youtube.gr
www.youtube.gt
www.youtube.hk
www.youtube.hr
www.youtube.hu
www.youtube.ie
www.youtube.in
www.youtube.iq
www.youtube.is
www.youtube.it
www.youtube.jo
www.youtube.jp
www.youtube.kr
www.youtube.kz
www.youtube.lk
www.youtube.lt
www.youtube.lu
www.youtube.lv
www.youtube.ly
www.youtube.ma
www.youtube.me
www.youtube.mk
www.youtube.mx
www.youtube.my
www.youtube.net.in
www.youtube.ng
www.youtube.ni
www.youtube.nl
www.youtube.no
www.youtube.pa
www.youtube.pe
www.youtube.ph
www.youtube.pk
www.youtube.pl
www.youtube.pr
www.youtube.pt
www.youtube.qa
www.youtube.ro
www.youtube.rs
www.youtube.ru
www.youtube.sa
www.youtube.se
www.youtube.sg
www.youtube.si
www.youtube.sk
www.youtube.sn
www.youtube.sv
www.youtube.tn
www.youtube.tv
www.youtube.ua
www.youtube.ug
www.youtube.uy
www.youtube.vn
www.youtube.voto
```

**There are also the following domains which are not included in the table**:

- m.youtube.com
- m.youtube.`<country code>`
- youtu.be (with and without the trailing dot)
- `<country code>`.youtube.com (e.g. jp.youtube.com)
- youtube.com. (with the trailing dot)
- youtube.`<country code>.` (with the trailing dot)
- domains like `gaming.youtube.com` in YouTube's sitemap https://www.youtube.com/sitemaps/sitemap.xml (see linked sub-sitemaps)

For comprehensiveness, I went through Wikipedia's 676 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes, took all possible two-letter language codes and appended them to the URL as `https://www.youtube.com/?gl=<language code>`, retrieved the URL, and checked if the source code contained the text `"gl":"<language code>"`. If the language code is not found (e.g. `ZZZZZ`), the source code will use the default language code of `"gl":"CA"`. Additionally, I went through Mozilla's Public Suffix list https://wiki.mozilla.org/Public_Suffix_List and took all of those and tried every single one.

Here are the following URLs that I couldn't find a corresponding TLD for (it doesn't imply that there should be one, however) which had the TLD code in the URL also in the HTML source:

```
https://www.youtube.com/?gl=CY
https://www.youtube.com/?gl=LI
https://www.youtube.com/?gl=NP
https://www.youtube.com/?gl=PG
https://www.youtube.com/?gl=YE
```

Bash script to get URL redirects (sometimes this script doesn't follow the redirect; I am not sure if it is because of my flaky internet, a rate-limit, or because of the script):

```
while read line; do echo "$line -> "$(curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} $line); done < youtube_urls.txt;
```

Comment: Good reference, however did you also test that really all these domains actually work?

Comment: @jave.web I tested the "Here are all of the URLs which redirected to youtube.com" table's links using the script and got the redirects; I spot checked five domains by replacing "youtube.com" in some video links and they successfully redirected to youtube.com.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some of the main domains, subdomains and gTLDs related to youtube

1st Level (domains):

```
.googlevideo.com
.youtu.be
.youtube.com
.youtube.com.br
.youtube.co.nz
.youtube.de
.youtube.es
.youtube.it
.youtube.nl
.youtube-nocookie.com
.youtube.ru
.ytimg.com
```

2nd Level (subdomains):

```
.video-stats.l.google.com
.youtube.googleapis.com
.youtubei.googleapis.com
.ytimg.l.google.com
```

gTLD:

```
.youtube
```

gTLD subdomains:

```
.rewind.youtube
.blog.youtube
```

Answer (score 1):

There's even .youtube, which is quite cool I think.

See https://lifeinaday.youtube/ for example.

Comment: Saw this recently. It's most probably an internal domain name.

Answer (score 0):

By this page http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt
There is also a .youtube domain itself.
As in the domain https://rewind.youtube
This gave me an idea. Why not use these domains as channel redirects.
eg. My channel (WMTV) will have the domain https://wmtv.youtube
Of course, this would be limited to bigger creators, but as time goes on, this might be a great feature from an individual YouTuber´s marketing standpoint.

Comment: Good point, but you should rather suggest this to YouTube aka Google, not here :) , also @nabakin already pointed this out 2 years ago :)

Comment: Oh, now I see. I have not seen it before, nvm.